# How to do calculation on time values imported from Excel?

Tags: matlab, time

I have the following values in Excel:

- Bed time 19:34:00
- Get up time  07:04:00
- Time in bed  11:30:00
- Sleep start  19:42:00
- Sleep end    07:00:00

I want to import them into MATLAB and do some calculation on these time values such as subtraction. The time values look like this after importing:

- 0.8153
- 0.2944
- 0.4792
- 0.8208
- 0.2917

and obviously doing calculation on them would be nonsense. Would any body help me with this issue? I have stuck with it for few days, and no progress yet.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: these are fractions of days - for example, sleep end = 7am = 7/24 = 0.291666... You can convert the numbers back to hours/minutes/seconds with basic arithmetic operations.

Comment: @assylias there doesn't seem to be a dupe that I can find for the MATLAB tag, can you please post this as an answer?

Comment: @excaza I don't know much about matlab so I wouldn't know how to express that in code - feel free to post the answer.

Comment: You can re-transform your number into string with (for example): `datestr(0.8208,'HH:MM:SS');`. But of course it is more convenient to do calculation with number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As assylias pointed out, these are fractions of days. You can use the [`datestr`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) function to convert it to human-readable strings with formatting option conveniently.

e.g.:

```
datestr(0.2917, 'HH:MM:SS')

ans =    
07:00:02
```

Calculations such as subtractions can be done on the raw values before 
conversion.

E.g: get duration of sleep.

```
start = 0.8208
stop = 0.2917

datestr(stop-start, 'HH:MM')

ans =
11:18
```

Even works for intervals that span over midnight.